Finding points closest to latitude and longitude using GeoPandas
I am trying to find all shape points belonging to a certain region.
Basically I have a GeoPandas frame containing the latitude longitude as well as the geometry points for a region.
keys include  ID latitude longitude geometry

One approach is I can simply query the geopandas by using a bounding box
gpd.query('lattitude>59 and 'lattitude'<60 and 'longitude'>-114 and 'longitude'<-116)

But I am not sure this is the correct way as it might give me points that are too far away.
Is there a way to find points closest to the target latitude and longitude
Another approach I am using is to compute distance between every point and the target latitude and longitude,and then see if the distance is less than a threshold.
but setting the threshold is proving to be challenging. If I set it to 0.1 or 0.5 the end result is only 4 or 5 rows as compared to the query by bounding box which returns 45 rows.
This is the latest attempt to finding the closest points using distance metric
def dms_to_dd(degrees, minutes, seconds, direction):
    dd = degrees + minutes / 60 + seconds / 3600
    if direction in ['S', 'W']:
        dd = -dd
    return dd

files=glob.glob('data_package/*.shp')
gdfs=[gpd.read_file(file) for file in files]


gdf=gdfs[0]


target_lat = 59.1833
target_lon = -115.5833

# Create the target point
target_point = Point(target_lon, target_lat)
gdf = gdf.to_crs("EPSG:4326")
gdf['distance_to_target'] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.distance(target_point))
#target_point = gpd.GeoSeries([Point(target_lon, target_lat)], crs="EPSG:4326")




# Calculate distances to the target point
#gdf['distance'] = gdf.geometry.apply(lambda geom: geom.distance(target_point[0]))
#min_distance = gdf['distance'].min()
#tolerance=0.1
distance_std = gdf['distance_to_target'].std()

# Calculate the mean distance
distance_mean = gdf['distance_to_target'].mean()
min_distance = gdf['distance_to_target'].min()
tolerance = distance_mean + distance_std # 10% tolerance

# Filter for points that are within the minimum distance + tolerance
nearest_points_with_tolerance = gdf[gdf['distance_to_target'] <= min_distance + tolerance]

# Filter all points with the minimum distance
#nearest_points_gdf = gdf[np.isclose(gdf['distance'], min_distance, atol=tolerance)]


The problem with this is that the number of rows come out to be significantly less as compared to a simple search where we are seeing if  latitude lies between 59 and 60 and longitude lies between -114 and -116

Provide more information, because "correct way" is subjective and depends on your question/task/goal/...

working with separate lat/lon columns is usually slower (and more error prone) than using proper geometry objects that can be spatially indexed.

Not sure what you are looking for exactly, but you could have a look at this question to get some inspiration... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79063494/how-to-accelerate-getting-points-within-distance-using-two-dataframes/79063963#79063963

Pieter  i referred to that link and used it to compute a distance metric and then filter it based on minimum distance.But the final result has less rows(only 4)

You have two point layers and one are the border points of regions? Can you add a screenshot?
